# Inputs inside Bootstrap grid doesnt work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been playing with the Bootstrap grid and my goal is to make this screen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjzJz.jpg)

I used 4-8 scale, so the table is the 8 and search options is the 4.
I don't know why but the search rows doesnt respond to the mouse (as there something on them) - but does respond if I navigate to them using the tab button.

The code of this part is:

```html
<span class="row">
   <span class="col-sm-4"> <!-- The Search Options -->
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
    <!-- Search by Date --> 
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
    <span class="row">
      <span class="col-sm-12">
      Search by Date: <input type="date" ng-model="b.AllsearchDate">
      <button ng-click="b.AllsearchByDate()">
       <img alt="Search" src="../Ico/search.png" height="19px">
      </button> <br /> <br /> 
      </span>
     </span>
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
    <!-- Search by Price --> 
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
    <span class="row">
       <a class="col-sm-12">
      Search by Price: <input ng-model="b.AllsearchPrice"
      placeholder="Input max price...." type="number"/>
      <button ng-click="b.AllsearchByPrice()">
       <img alt="Search" src="../Ico/search.png" height="19px">
      </button> <br /> <br /> 
     </a>
     </span>
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
    <!-- Search by Category --> 
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
    <span class="row">
     <span class="col-sm-12">
      Search by Type: &nbsp <select ng-model="b.AllsearchType">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
       <option value="FOOD">Food</option>
       <option value="ELECTRICTY">Electricity</option>
       <option value="RESTAURANTS">Restaurants</option>
       <option value="HEALTH">Health</option>
       <option value="SPORTS">Sports</option>
       <option value="CAMPING">Camping</option>
       <option value="TRAVELLING">Traveling</option>
      </select>
    
      <button ng-click="b.AllsearchByType()">
       <img alt="Search" src="../Ico/search.png" height="19px">
      </button> <br /> <br />
     </span>
    </span>
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
   </span> <!-- col-sm-4 -->
  <!-- ================================================================================== -->
  <!-- All Coupons table --> 
  <!-- ================================================================================== -->
  <table border="1" class="col-sm-8">
   <tr>
    <th ng-click="b.orderBy('id')">ID</th>
    <th ng-click="b.orderBy('title')">Title</th>
    <th ng-click="b.orderBy('start_date')">Start Date</th>
    <th ng-click="b.orderBy('end_date')">End date</th>
    <th ng-click="b.orderBy('amount')">Amount</th>
    <th ng-click="b.orderBy('type')">Type</th>
    <th ng-click="b.orderBy('message')">Message</th>
    <th ng-click="b.orderBy('price')">Price</th>
    <th ng-click="b.orderBy('image')">Image</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="c1 in b.allCoupons | orderBy: b.order : b.goUp">
    <td>{{c1.id}}</td>
    <td>{{c1.title}}</td>
    <td>{{c1.start_date}}</td>
    <td>{{c1.end_date}}</td>
    <td>{{c1.amount}}</td>
    <td>{{c1.type}}</td>
    <td>{{c1.message}}</td>
    <td>{{c1.price}}$</td>
    <td><img alt="" src={{c1.image}} width="100px" height="100px"></td>
    <td>
     <button ng-click="b.buy(c1)">
      <img alt="Buy" src="../Ico/buy.png" width="60px" height="60px">
     </button>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table> 
  <br/><br/>
  </span><!-- row -->
```

Can't find any solutions on the web, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `span` instead of `div`? for rows & columns? The proper way is to use divs not spans for cols and rows.

**This should help.**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <!-- The Search Options -->
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
    <!-- Search by Date -->
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        Search by Date:
        <input type="date" ng-model="b.AllsearchDate">
        <button ng-click="b.AllsearchByDate()">
                    <img alt="Search" src="../Ico/search.png" height="19px">
                </button>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
    <!-- Search by Price -->
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
    <div class="row">
      <a class="col-sm-12">
                Search by Price:
                <input ng-model="b.AllsearchPrice" placeholder="Input max price...." type="number" />
                <button ng-click="b.AllsearchByPrice()">
                    <img alt="Search" src="../Ico/search.png" height="19px">
                </button>
                <br />
                <br />
            </a>
    </div>
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
    <!-- Search by Category -->
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        Search by Type: &nbsp
        <select ng-model="b.AllsearchType">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Type</option>
                    <option value="FOOD">Food</option>
                    <option value="ELECTRICTY">Electricity</option>
                    <option value="RESTAURANTS">Restaurants</option>
                    <option value="HEALTH">Health</option>
                    <option value="SPORTS">Sports</option>
                    <option value="CAMPING">Camping</option>
                    <option value="TRAVELLING">Traveling</option>
                </select>
        <button ng-click="b.AllsearchByType()">
                    <img alt="Search" src="../Ico/search.png" height="19px">
                </button>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
  </div>
  <!-- col-sm-4 -->
  <!-- ================================================================================== -->
  <!-- All Coupons table -->
  <!-- ================================================================================== -->
  <table border="1" class="col-sm-8">
    <tr>
      <th ng-click="b.orderBy('id')">ID</th>
      <th ng-click="b.orderBy('title')">Title</th>
      <th ng-click="b.orderBy('start_date')">Start Date</th>
      <th ng-click="b.orderBy('end_date')">End date</th>
      <th ng-click="b.orderBy('amount')">Amount</th>
      <th ng-click="b.orderBy('type')">Type</th>
      <th ng-click="b.orderBy('message')">Message</th>
      <th ng-click="b.orderBy('price')">Price</th>
      <th ng-click="b.orderBy('image')">Image</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="c1 in b.allCoupons | orderBy: b.order : b.goUp">
      <td>{{c1.id}}</td>
      <td>{{c1.title}}</td>
      <td>{{c1.start_date}}</td>
      <td>{{c1.end_date}}</td>
      <td>{{c1.amount}}</td>
      <td>{{c1.type}}</td>
      <td>{{c1.message}}</td>
      <td>{{c1.price}}$</td>
      <td><img alt="" src={{c1.image}} width="100px" height="100px"></td>
      <td>
        <button ng-click="b.buy(c1)">
                    <img alt="Buy" src="../Ico/buy.png" width="60px" height="60px">
                </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</div>
<!-- row -->
```

Comment: okay, but "div" get more of the screen that I want, what else I can use that will work as "div" but will not have this huge blocks?

Comment: use smaller col sizes and offsets.